# if contains two words

Tags: java, if-statement, contains

I am brand new at coding and can not get my application to run right. Please help!

I have written the following code for a HW assignment:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HW1Q2
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String sentence, str1, str2;

        System.out.println("Enter a sentence containing either the word \"blue\" or the word \"green\" both or neither");
        sentence = keyboard.nextLine();
        str1 = "blue";
        str2 = "green";

        if(sentence.contains("blue")); if(sentence.contains("green")){
            System.out.println("sunny");}
        else{
        if(sentence.contains("blue")){
            System.out.println("ocean");}
        else{
        if(sentence.contains("green")){
            System.out.println("garden");}
        else{
            System.out.println("dull");
        }}}
    }
}
```

The goal is to return

- `garden` if they type `green`
- `ocean` if they type `blue`
- `sunny` if they type both and
- `dull` if they type neither

The problem is if I write a sentence that only includes `green`, it still returns `sunny` not `garden`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use `&&` as an AND to check for blue and green. Something like the logic below should work. The order is critical. You have to check for the both words before you start checking for either word. Otherwise you always print out ocean or garden before you can print sunny.

```
    if(sentence.contains("blue") && sentence.contains("green")) {
        System.out.println("sunny");
    } else if (sequence.contains("blue")) {
        System.out.println("ocean");
    } else if (sequence.contains("green")) {    
        System.out.println("garden");
    } else {
        System.out.println("dull");
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is here:

```
if(sentence.contains("blue")); if(sentence.contains("green")){
    System.out.println("sunny");}
```

The first `if` does nothing at all, because it is followed by an empty statement `;`. The second is the reason why you get `sunny` when `green` is entered.

I guess you wanted to combine these with the logical and operator `&&`:

```
if(sentence.contains("blue") && sentence.contains("green")){
    System.out.println("sunny");}
```